R read zip-file, gpkg-file with terra vect()
I have two questions on applying vect of the package terra with files from an opendata-source.

I would like to read the shp-file with vect from the directory "Amphibien_LV95" within the zip-file "data" without downloading and unzipping the file locally.

link <- https://data.geo.admin.ch/ch.bafu.bundesinventare-amphibien/data.zip

Unfortunately my attempts with unz and unzip in combination with vect() were not successful.

I would like to read a gpkg-File from an http-address (in special the layer=ElectricityProductionPlant)

link <- "https://data.geo.admin.ch/ch.bfe.elektrizitaetsproduktionsanlagen/gpkg/2056/ch.bfe.elektrizitaetsproduktionsanlagen.gpkg"

data <- vect(link)

With vect() I get the error:
Error: [vect] cannot read this geometry type: Unknown (any) 
If I read the link with st_read and then  transform it with vect it works. Why?
a <- st_read(link)
data <- vect(a)


VSI handlers can also be chained, so we could use zip + curl for the 1st:
library(terra)
#> terra 1.7.83
zip_link <- "https://data.geo.admin.ch/ch.bafu.bundesinventare-amphibien/data.zip"
(vsi <- paste("/vsizip", "/vsicurl", zip_link, "Amphibien_LV95", sep = "/" ))
#> [1] "/vsizip//vsicurl/https://data.geo.admin.ch/ch.bafu.bundesinventare-amphibien/data.zip/Amphibien_LV95"
vector_layers(vsi)
#> [1] "am_A3"              "amphibLaichgebiet"  "amphibWanderobjekt"
vect(vsi, layer = "amphibLaichgebiet")[,1:4]
#>  class       : SpatVector 
#>  geometry    : polygons 
#>  dimensions  : 1448, 4  (geometries, attributes)
#>  extent      : 2486326, 2830988, 1075278, 1291233  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#>  source      : Amphibien_LV95 (amphibLaichgebiet)
#>  coord. ref. : CH1903+ / LV95 (EPSG:2056) 
#>  names       : ObjNummer           Name                RefObjBlat DesignatTy
#>  type        :     <chr>          <chr>                     <chr>      <chr>
#>  values      :       AG3 Zurlindeninsel https://data.geo.admin.c~        NDA
#>                     AG19       Halbmond https://data.geo.admin.c~        NDA
#>                     AG19       Halbmond https://data.geo.admin.c~        NDA


Great thanks! Additional question: is it possible to list the files/directories of zip_link so that I don't have to know in advance the name of the favorite directory - e.g. "Amphibien_LV95"?

In this particular case I'd just check it from web - https://data.geo.admin.ch/ch.bafu.bundesinventare-amphibien . You can also get a trucated list of files in a error message if you call something like vect("/vsizip//vsicurl/https://data.geo.admin.ch/ch.bafu.bundesinventare-amphibien/data.zip/").  If you have GDAL installed, you can use ogrinfo, e.g. system2("C:/Program Files/QGIS 3.38.3/bin/ogrinfo", "/vsizip//vsicurl/https://data.geo.admin.ch/ch.bafu.bundesinventare-amphibien/data.zip/"). Or if you don't mind another package (and another bundled GDAL in Win), vapour::vapour_vsi_list()

This is what you can do for #1 (it is a zip file with folders and multiple layers (shapefiles), so you need to know some of its structure)
library(terra)

url <- "https://data.geo.admin.ch/ch.bafu.bundesinventare-amphibien/data.zip"
link <- paste0("/vsizip//vsicurl/", url, "/Amphibien_LV03")
v <- vect(link, layer="amphibLaichgebiet")
v
# class       : SpatVector 
# geometry    : polygons 
# dimensions  : 1448, 11  (geometries, attributes)
# extent      : 486326.3, 830986.7, 75279.51, 291233.5  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
# source      : Amphibien_LV03 (amphibLaichgebiet)
# coord. ref. : CH1903 / LV03 (EPSG:21781) 
# names       : ObjNummer           Name      RefObjBlat DesignatTy IUCNCatego Inkraftset Mutationsd Mutationsg Bereich Shape_Leng Shape_Area
# type        :     <chr>          <chr>           <chr>      <chr>      <chr>      <chr>      <chr>      <chr>   <chr>      <num>      <num>
# values      :       AG3 Zurlindeninsel https://data.g~        NDA         IV 2001/08/01 0000/00/00         NA       A       3429  1.702e+05
#                    AG19       Halbmond https://data.g~        NDA         IV 2001/08/01 0000/00/00         NA       A       3482  1.802e+05
#                    AG19       Halbmond https://data.g~        NDA         IV 2001/08/01 0000/00/00         NA       B       3466    1.2e+05

And #2 works out of the box
url <- "https://data.geo.admin.ch/ch.bfe.elektrizitaetsproduktionsanlagen/gpkg/2056/ch.bfe.elektrizitaetsproduktionsanlagen.gpkg"
d <- vect(url)
d
# class       : SpatVector 
# geometry    : points 
# dimensions  : 235434, 11  (geometries, attributes)
# extent      : 2486221, 2831207, 1075930, 1294815  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
# source      : ch.bfe.elektrizitaetsproduktionsanlagen.gpkg (ElectricityProductionPlant)
# coord. ref. : CH1903+ / LV95 (EPSG:2056) 
# names       : xtf_id           Address PostCode Municipality Canton BeginningOfOperation InitialPower TotalPower MainCategory SubCategory #PlantCategory
# type        :  <int>             <chr>    <int>        <chr>  <chr>                <chr>        <num>      <num>        <chr>       <chr>         <chr>
# values      :  14727 Schlossstrasse 15     4147     Aesch BL     BL           2009-05-05        14.65      18.81    maincat_2    subcat_2    plantcat_9
#                14728    Ob der Steig 1     5082      Kaisten     AG           2011-10-28          5.8        5.8    maincat_2    subcat_2    plantcat_8
#                10164          Gässli 4     3114    Wichtrach     BE           2008-10-07            3          3    maincat_2    subcat_2    plantcat_8


#2: Strange - perhaps I don't have all the newest packages - I'll try once more
